Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 130, returning the closest version; found: 129 & Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium. etc
I've recently started getting into learning selenium and java on its own, been following a course online however keep receiving these two error messages when trying to do so, the code is essentially meant to find the google browser and input the text into the search bar automatically, but it loads up google and does nothing.
Code:
package test;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    test();
    

}

public static void test() {
    
    System.getProperty("WebDriver.chrome.driver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    //go to google.com
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    
    //enter text in search box
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Automation step by step");
    
    //click on search button
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click();
    
    //close browser
    driver.close();`your text`
    
    System.out.println("Test completed");
    
}
}

Console:
Oct 30, 2024 9:49:24 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 130, returning the closest version; found: 129; Please update to a Selenium version that supports CDP version 130
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

What can I do to fix this, as I'm completely new to this and a bit confused by the error

WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 130, returning the closest version; found: 129; Please update to a Selenium version that supports CDP version 130

You can ignore the above. It's just a Warning and not and Exception. Basically warning is just about the chromedriver.exe and chrome version mismatch.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Above exception is your real issue. It seems like selenium is not able to interact with the targeted element as some other element is covering the target element. I think in this case it is, Accept/Reject cookies pop-up.
Try getting rid of the pop-up by clicking on Accept all button before you send text to the google search.
Check the code below:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Accept all']")).click();
//enter text in search box
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Automation step by step");


Thank you so much, it worked. So essentially was it due to the pop up every time when chrome was being opened? and that line of code essentially just accepts it so theres no delay im assuming

That's correct. When Selenium launches browser, it launches in a clean browse profile, so you will get such cookies pop-up each time. You just need to click either on Accept or Reject so that it gets closed.

the warning is about CDP bindings.... those are included with the Selenium Jar.  (Updating Selenium might help for the warning, but it's not necessary... it's for Chrome Dev Tools Protocol... so browser version vs. selenium's CDP bindings version)

Update to your latest org.seleniumhq.selenium version.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
